# Why am I getting an error with this abstract method?

Tags: java

I am getting the following error with this code:

```
BankingServant is not abstract and does not override abstract method
CheckBalance(String) in BankingOperations public class BankingServant
extends _BankingImplBase
```

Here is my code:

```java
import BankingApp._BankingImplBase;
import BankingApp.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class BankingServant extends _BankingImplBase {
  private int AccountName;
  private int LodgementAmount ;
  private int TransferAmount ;
  private int WithdrawlAmount;
  private int TransferAmount;
  private int TransferAccWith;
  private int TransferAccDep;
  private int CheckBalance;

  private class Account {
    String accName;
  }

  private class Trans {
    String accName;
    double transferAmount;
    double transferAccWith;
    double transferAccDep;
    double withAmount;
    double lodgementAmount;
  }

  private class With {
    String accName;
    double withAmount;
  }

  public boolean Lodgement(String accName, double lodgementAmount) {
    System.out.println("Enter Lodgement.");
    Account acc = new Account();
    acc.accName = accName;
    acc.lodgementAmount = lodgementAmount;
    acc.add(acc);
    System.out.println("Money was lodged.");
  }

  public boolean Transfer(String accName, double transferAmount, double transferAccWith, double transferAccDep){
    System.out.println("Transfer Amount: ");
    Trans bankingTemp = new Trans();
    bankingTemp.accName = accName;
    bankingTemp.transferAmount = transferAmount;
    bankingTemp.transferAccWith = transferAccWith;
    bankingTemp.transferAccDep = transferAccDep;
    bankingTemp.parts = this.parts;
    bankingTemp.planeId = planeId;
    banking.add(bankingTemp);
    System.out.println("Transfered");
    planeId++;
    return true;
  }

  public void CheckBalance(String accName) {
    System.out.println("Balance is: ");
    Account accB = new Account();
    accB.accName = accName;
    accB.checkBalance = checkBalance;
    accB.add(accB);
    System.out.println("Balance is: ");
  }
}
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: can you post what error are you getting?

Comment: what's the method signature of `CheckBalance` in the abstract class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
private int CheckBalance;
```

and

```
public void CheckBalance(String accName) {
```

There are two Java conventions you can follow to prevent things like this:

1. Always begin method and field names with a lowercase letter.
2. **more important in this example** Fields should be given **noun** names, methods should be given **verb** names, so they should almost never have the same name.

You can find some good references on naming conventions here:

- [Java Code Naming Conventions](http://www.appperfect.com/support/java-coding-rules/namingconvention.html)
- [Java Practices](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=58)

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that your `CheckBalance` methods in `BankingServant` and `_BankingImplBase` have different signatures. It looks like they have the same parameter so perhaps it has a different return type.